# Why transaction not be rolled back between a web service and database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm using `system.Transactions` around a web service and a database.  The transaction doesn't roll back when I can't connect to remote database. so the data is inserted in the database of web service while should be rolled back.  I'm writing web service code my self.  Distributed transaction coordinator service is run and I set the other parameters in Component Services.

It's better to say both Web service and client are in the same machine.

```
using System.Transactions;

 try
{
    using (TransactionScope tscope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        //----- Web service
        IdentificationSystem.Service Identify = new IdentificationSystem.Service();
        Identify.InsertWorkshopInfo(BosWorkshop.WpSvUserName,          BosWorkshop.WpSvPassword,BosWorkshop.WkIcode
        //-------------
        //------------------ connect to a remote DB
        //--------- My Sql Query
        string sq= "SET XACT_ABORT ON;update tbl_kargah " +
            "set email_kargah=email_kargah+@WpCode "+
            "where co_kargah=@co_kargah "+
            "insert into dbo.tbl_WorkshopCodes (co_kargah,Code_ostan,Wpcode) "+
            "values(@Co_kargah,@Code_ostan,@WpCode) "+
            "insert into LnkWorkerSystem.Bazresi_kar.dbo.tbl_Workshopcodes(Co_Kargah,Code_Ostan,WpCode) "+
            "values(@Co_kargah,@Code_ostan,@WpCode) ";

        //--------
        SqlCon = new SqlConnection(@BoBaz.BazConnectionString);
        SqlCon.Open();
        SqlCom = new SqlCommand(sq, SqlCon);
        SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@co_kargah", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = BoBaz.BazCodeKargah;
        SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Code_ostan", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = BoBaz.BazCodeOstan;
        SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@WpCode", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = BoBaz.WpRealCode;
        SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlCon.Close();

        tscope.Complete();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    string s = ex.Message;
}
```

Refer to this question please:[Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640538/is-transaction-between-a-web-service-and-a-database-possible)

Comment: You have an unfinished return statement before your SQL...

Comment: I just copied it from my code I revised it

Comment: @Raymond Morphy:you say:"the transaction doesn't roll back when I can't connect to remote database" I wonder if you don't connect to database what kind of transaction should do rollback and what kind of insert performs!!!!

Comment: The first time I connect to web service and some records will be inserted in the database of web service and then I want to connect to my remote database but I can't connect to it so the data that is inserted in web service should be deleted(Rolled back)

Comment: @Raymond Morphy:So you have 2 database that are separate? if database are seperate and not on one server you can't do your work transactionally.

Comment: So what about distributed transactions?

Comment: according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction you must have 1 transaction manager.do you have 1 transaction manager?

Comment: I think so. you can refer to my code this all things I have written

Comment: I think you are wrong.transaction managersa are RDBMSs such as Sql Server and not related to your code.

Comment: So what should I do? I want a transaction between  my web service and my database.I found an article here.[Web servicetransaction](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/TransactionASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

After lots of dialog, it would seem you are using an ASMX web service. These are ***basic*** web-services, and do not support this usage.

Increased support for this is given by things like WCF *in certain modes* (not all), and requires additional configuration. However, personally my advice is: DON'T. Distributed transactions are tricky enough for things like SQL on a local LAN - add web services into the mix and it is usually asking for trouble (is my opinion).

However, some people get along with these just fine - YMMV.

---

Here's your error:

```
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
     string s = ex.Message;
 }
```

Your code is probably **trying to tell you what is wrong**, but you went and swallowed the exception.

My guess is that another element in the distributed transaction (maybe a WCF call) failed, dooming the entire transaction. The exception *will tell you this*.

IMO, remove the `catch` block *completely*. If bad things happen, don't hide them and then wonder what happened. Let it bubble up to the top level, where your existing (cough) central error handling will *of course* write that error into the error log that you check frequently.

Comment: My problem is: the exception occurs but the web service function not be rolled back

Comment: @Raymond and which WCF binding are you using? Not all support transactions... you also need additional steps to enable them: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFTransactions.aspx

Comment: I don't use WCF I use ASMX web services

Comment: @Raymond - ASMX is not transactional... transactions need lots of extra hooks.

Comment: Gravell what should I do? Please give me a solution

Comment: @Raymond - one of: move to a protocol that supports transactions (WCF with transactions enabled, for example); or: live without transactions; or: use a compensator call after it has failed